# Don't install Phonegap in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, phonegap

I am following **[this](http://mobileangularui.com/blog/using-the-generator/)** Mobile Phonegap app tutorial.

I'm using NodeJS version v8.2.1.

I did the steps: `npm install -g bower yo gulp generator-mobileangularui`, but receive the following messages in console:

[image]

What is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Thien! Those are just **warnings**. They are **non-breaking** log-level information for the NPM installation process, meaning they can be ignored. Please update your question with more relevant info... as it stands there is too little information given. Post a print-screen of an error in the console, not of warnings.

Comment: I waited a long time but the installation process was not continued(Two hours)

Comment: I would look for the following: **1.** are your 'buntu **software repositories** up-to-date?; **2.** check online for open issues with `phonegap` on Linux-based OSs; **3.** check for networking issues: are you behind a proxy, do you have connectivity with the remote repo, etc. Out-of-the-box, your issue is hard to debug. I would start with the above and try to narrow-down the possible issues.

Comment: Hi iamdanchiv!
1 .are your 'buntu software repositories up-to-date?
     How to update my ubuntu software respositoris?
3. check for networking issues:
     My network is not issues